# How to handle missing images URL in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC view that has several images(1- per page).

Example:

```
<img alt ='thumb1' src='<%= Model.ThumbnailURL %>' height="65" width="90" />
```

The problem is Model may or may not have a ThumbnailURL which results in an object reference not set message.

How can prevent the images from loading when they do not exists. I do not want to use a default image

Answer (score 1):

Put an if statement around it.

```
<% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ThumbnailURL)) { %>
<img alt ='thumb1' src='<%= Model.ThumbnailURL %>' height="65" width="90" />
<% } %>
```

edit:
Changed to WebForms view engine, I assumed you were using Raser.

Comment: I am not using RAZER. I am aware that I can put an if statement to verify if the model.ThumbnailURL  is empty but I thought that would look nasty since there are 10 images. I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this

Answer (score 0):

To get around the *NRE* (null reference exception) use the *[Null Coalescing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)* `??`:

```
<img alt ="thumb1"
     src="<%= Model.ThumbnailURL ?? "" %>"
     height="65"
     width="90" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I am still getting the (null reference exception)

Comment: if you still get a Null Reference Exception, are you sure it's not `Model` that's null?

Comment: @user1526912 make sure you're passing the model, (i.e. `return View(model)`). I've seen this many times, people think there is something wrong with their model, when its only that they're not passing it to the view.